# Como resolver espacio en blanco (Android)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo un XML de Android que implementa un AutoCompleteTextView. La cosa es que me gustaria ponerlo debajo y si lo muevo se genera un espacio en blanco entre la barra superior y el AutoCompleteTextView. Alguna solución?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
tools:context="sharetaxi.sharetaxiuser.Map"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:orientation="vertical">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/query"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas definiendo en el contenedor un:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Esto esta generando un margen con el tamaño de la ActionBar.

Elimina esta propiedad de tu `LinearLayout` principal, para quitar el espacio en blanco que comentas.

Así se muestra actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se mostraría eliminando la propiedad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eliminando la propiedad y añadiendo un margen me sigue saliendo el espacio en blanco

Comment: no debes añadir nada solo eliminar la propiedad que comento.

Comment: exacto, como dice Elenasys , deberias quitar por completo el margin para que no se visualize